# Разница val и var в полиморфизме Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

В чем заключается разница между var и val, если у меня есть открытый класс, в котором я пропишу свойство open (var/val) x = 1,а затем в наследуемом подклассе использую override (var/val) x = 2, результат ведь будет одинаковый и код скомпилируется, или я что-то упустил? В чем разница?

Comment: не совсем ясна суть проблемы. а что вы хотите увидеть? var /val - это можно ли изменять переменную. а override - это "перезапись" переменной. вы можете в родительской классе написать val x : Int? = null а дочернем override var x: Int = 1. и все будет работать правильно.

Comment: var/val это о mutability, которое к полиморфизму не имеет прямого отношения.